# How to get viewing height or pitch angle from a bing map?

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I am using the v7.0 Ajax control from Bing Maps and I'm trying to get the following information while being in the bird's eye view mode on the map:

- the viewing height (or altitude) -- this is the zoom level, right?
- the pitch angle -- does this always has the same value, no matter of the viewing angle while being in the bird's eye view mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as the "altitude" at which a projected map image is created. There is a map scale and resolution (i.e. how many metres each screen pixel corresponds to) which varies according to the zoom level and the location on the earth's surface, but this does not correlate to the view you would get if you were looking down at the earth from x metres above it.

The angle at which Bird's eye imagery is shot varies in different scenes - you can observe this as you pan around the map - the imagery will clearly warp as you move from one scene to the next.